# Send selected datagridview to datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to get a selected datagridview row to a datatable.

With the following code I am able to send the selectedrow over, however when trying to send a second row to the datatable, it adds an empty row but overwrites the first row in the datatable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridview.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
        {
            DT1.Rows.Add();

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridview.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                DT1.Rows[0][j] = dataGridview.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;
            }
        }
```

As expected it enters the row on index 0, so i tried the folowing to get to the last row

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridview.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                int rowcount = DT1.Rows.Count;
                DT1.Rows[rowcount][j] = dataGridview.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;
            }
```

This gives me an error that the row does not exist, what should be the solution to add a second row instead of replacing?

Comment: arrays are 0 based, so don't access Rows[rowcount], access Rows[rowcount-1] to get to the last row,.

Comment: Thank you Les, this works great, also tried int rowcount = CarProfile.Rows.Count -1; but this wouldn't work. Could you post the anwser so I can give you the credits?

Comment: Count-1 is not the rowcount.  rowcount is .Count.  Count-1  or rowcount-1 is the **last row**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got other problems in your code.  Namely, if your user selects the same rows in different calls to this code, you will insert duplicates.

Fix rowcount, changing it to rowcount-1.  Then review your design.  Come up with an approach to prevent duplicate insertions (unless you really want that).

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in `rowcount`

Rowcount gives you total no of rows but `rowindex` always starts with 0 
ie `rowindex = rowcount-1` 
use this

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridview.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    int rowcount = DT1.Rows.Count;
    DT1.Rows[rowcount-1][j] = dataGridview.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DT1.Rows[i][j] = dataGridview.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value,ToString();
```

Try this! Your outer loop is already keeping track of the rows in your tables so there's no need to mess with the row count.